# by/until which one and why?

Tags: grammar

I think I'll be wait by/until thursday before making a decision .

which one and WHY?

"I think I'll wait until Thursday before I make a decision." is correct. Explanation is the same. "I am not going to make the decision sooner than on Thursday." "By" would mean on Thursday or sooner which does not make sense.
.....

With regard to the top definitions, If I would make  a decision sooner than thursday or on thursday, must I use the preposition"by" instead of "until"? that is,

I think I'll be wait by thursday before making a decision .

Comment: There is an answer already at [by 5.30 or until 5.30/ why future tense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143938/by-5-30-or-until-5-30-why-future-tense) -- viz., [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143960/18696).

Answer (score 1):

"I will wait by Thursday to make a decision" is not grammatical.

If you want to postpone making a decision until Thursday, you say "I will wait until Thursday to make a decision."

If you want to say that you will make a decision anytime between now and Thursday, you can say "I will make a decision by Thursday".